# CROSS JOIN with later PIVOT going rather slowly

Tags: sql-server-2014, optimization

I have an operation that is going rather slowly, probably because my `CROSS JOIN` first creates a ton of rows for SQL Server to work on, which are later `GROUP`ed and `PIVOT`ed into far fewer rows and a bunch of columns.  The aim is to get the "times each record was downloaded" per "unique organization name", where the unique organization names are the unique `OrganizationName` entries in the `AdamUser` table and the times downloaded is the number of associated entries in the `MaintenanceJobHistory` table.  Lastly, `Record` is joined onto each row to output more info about that record.  Here's the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        rec.[Id]                                      AS RecordId,
        CONCAT('Downloads_', usr.[OrganizationName])  AS OrganizationName,
        COUNT(hist.[Id])                              AS TimesDownloaded  -- To be aggregated by PIVOT
    FROM (
        SELECT
            innerRec.[Id]
        FROM
            [dbo].[Record] innerRec
        INNER JOIN
            [dbo].[RecordClassificationLink] innerLnk ON innerLnk.[RecordId] = innerRec.[Id]
        -- WHERE (classification ID is foo or bar), for optional classification filtering
        GROUP BY
            innerRec.[Id]
        -- HAVING COUNT(innerLnk.ClassificationId) = (number of specified classifications), for optional classification filtering
    ) rec
    CROSS JOIN [dbo].[AdamUser] usr
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT * FROM [dbo].[MaintenanceJobHistory] WHERE [CreatedOn] > '2016-01-01 12:00:00' AND [CreatedOn] < '2016-12-01 12:00:00'
    ) hist ON hist.[AccessingUser] = usr.[Name] AND hist.[RecordId] = rec.[Id]
    GROUP BY
        rec.[Id], usr.[OrganizationName]
) srcTable
PIVOT  -- Pivot around columns outside aggregation fn, eg. heading column [OrganizationName] & all other columns: [RecordId]
(
    MIN(srcTable.[TimesDownloaded]) FOR [OrganizationName] IN (...~200 columns...)
) pivotTable
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Record] outerRec ON outerRec.[Id] = pivotTable.[RecordId]
```

And here's the execution plan:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ry8tXM3mg

It does give me the correct output, but I noticed that the Sort operation before the Stream Aggregate is taking a long time, and spills into `tempdb`.  This may be why the query takes ~5 minutes with the ~200 columns I have for the normal dataset, whereas my test dataset with 6 columns in the `PIVOT` only takes maybe half a minute.  In terms of how many rows it's dealing with, the two tables being `CROSS JOIN`ed (`Record` and `AdamUser`) have 38397 and 1017 rows respectively.

Is there a way I can speed this up, or is it necessary to take this long for the number of rows and columns I have?

Comment: Things to try: **(1)** [Query Hint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx) `OPTION(HASH GROUP)`, **(2)** Old-school pivot using aggregation.

Comment: If you remove the `PIVOT` and run the inner subquery - how does the performance change?

Comment: What do you mean the inner subquery?

Comment: If you mean all of the query before the `PIVOT`, that executes in about half the time.

Comment: @TT. Adding `OPTION(HASH GROUP)` is making it take way longer (in fact it's still running), so that doesn't seem to be very useful.

Comment: @Jez What's the plan for that part of the query?

Comment: I don't have the plan as it's still executing.  Is there a way to cancel a query in SSMS but still get the plan returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any way to speed up the `PIVOT` operation - it's just a big operation that takes time with a lot of data.  The one thing I did that seemed to speed things up a small amount (perhaps the addition concatenation operator implemented more efficiently in SQL Server) was to change `CONCAT('Downloads_', usr.[OrganizationName])` to `'Downloads_' + usr.[OrganizationName]`.  The rest seems to be pretty much optimal.